# Translate function from python to pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to compare two pyspark dataframes and get the differences in a new table.

I tested the way to do it using python:

my dataframe

```
data = {'name': ['NO_VALUE', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
    'year': [2012, -999999, 2013, 2014, 2014],
    'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])
df3
```

my reference dataframe

```
data_ref = {'name': ['Jaso', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
    'year': [2012, 202, 2013, 2014, 2014],
    'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
df_ref3 = pd.DataFrame(data_ref, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])
df_ref3
```

Compare rows:

```
def compare_datasets(df, df_ref):
    ne_stacked = (df != df_ref).stack()
    changed = ne_stacked[ne_stacked]
    changed.index.names = ['id', 'col']
    difference_locations = np.where(df != df_ref)
    changed_from = df.values[difference_locations]
    changed_to = df_ref.values[difference_locations]
    error_test = pd.DataFrame({'from': changed_from, 'to': changed_to}, index=changed.index)
    return error_test

compare_datasets(df3, df_ref3)
```

However, I would like to do this in pyspark. Does someone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you are using `pandas` dataframe, not `pyspark`! in `pyspark` you have to convert your function into an `UDF`!

Comment: I know I have pandas dataframe. The fact is that I now want to do the same function but with pyspark dataframes and language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably difficult to reproduce exactly this behavior. 
I offer you one partial solution :

```
df.show()
+----------+--------+-------+-------+
|     index|    name|   year|reports|
+----------+--------+-------+-------+
|   Cochice|NO_VALUE|   2012|      4|
|      Pima|   Molly|-999999|     24|
|Santa Cruz|    Tina|   2013|     31|
|  Maricopa|    Jake|   2014|      2|
|      Yuma|     Amy|   2014|      3|
+----------+--------+-------+-------+

df_ref.show()
+----------+-----+----+-------+
|     index| name|year|reports|
+----------+-----+----+-------+
|   Cochice| Jaso|2012|      4|
|      Pima|Molly|2012|     24|
|Santa Cruz| Tina|2013|     31|
|  Maricopa| Jake|2014|      2|
|      Yuma|  Amy|2014|      3|
+----------+-----+----+-------+

df.subtract(df_ref).show()
+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|  index|    name|   year|reports|
+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|   Pima|   Molly|-999999|     24|
|Cochice|NO_VALUE|   2012|      4|
+-------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Or you can do the slow one :

```
for col in df_ref.columns:
  out = df.select(col).subtract(df_ref.select(col))
  if out.first():
    print(out.collect())

[Row(name=u'NO_VALUE')]
[Row(year=-999999)]
```